# Strings that begin with a given prefix

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public List<String> function(String pre) {
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String str : list) {
        if(str.startsWith(pre)
            temp.add(str);
        if(str.charAt(0) > pre.charAt(0))
            break;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

The function should return all words that begin with the given prefix.
list in the code is a sorted ArrayList. This code has `O(n)` complexity.
How can I improve it?
e.g. to run in `log(n)` time.

Comment: Have a look at tries for prefix searches if you exchange your data structure.

Comment: It's impossible to get this to run in better than O(n) in the number of strings in the list since you could have all strings (or a majority of them) start with the same prefix. You can only get a performance improvement if you have to do many searches multiple times..

Comment: There used to be an answer here noting that, since the list is sorted, you could find the beginning and end of the matching range with an O(log n) binary search and the call List.subList() to extract the range in O(1) time, regardless of how many words are found. It seems to have been deleted for some reason -- I have no idea why, since it seemed correct to me.

Comment: This is the question linked to in the now deleted answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218931/extension-of-binary-search-algo-to-find-the-first-and-last-index-of-the-key-valu

Answer (score 2):

Question is - can you do it in `O(logn)` time?
What if half of the elements in `list` have the desired prefix?
You need to add that half of the list to a new list - this is still `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
List<String> function(List<String> list, String pre) {
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String str : list) {
        if(str.startsWith(pre))
            temp.add(str);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: That's the same as mine.